# Can I move a to-do to another to-do list using API?

Tags: api, basecamp

I would like to move a to-do to another to-do list.  It is possible using API ?

Answer (score 2):

I came across [this](https://github.com/basecamp/bcx-api/issues/132) in my own searches.  Send the put request like

```
PUT https://basecamp.com/ACCOUNTID/api/v1/projects/PROJECTID/todos/TODOIT
```

with the following JSON in the body

```
{
    "todolist_id":NEWTODOLISTID,
}
```

NEWTODOLISTID is an integer and does not need quotes